# project the sum of values in a mongo subdocument

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a Mongo Collection that I'm trying to aggregate in which I need to be able to filter the results based on a sum of values from a subdocument. Each of my entries has a subdocument that looks like this

```
{
    "_id": <MongoId>,
    'clientID': 'some ID',
    <Other fields I can filter on normally>
    "bidCompData": [
        {
          "lineItemID": "210217",
          "qtyBid": 3,
          "priceBid": 10.25,
          "qtyComp": 0
          "description": "Lawn Mowed"
          "invoiceID": 23
        },
        {
          <More similar entries>
        }
    ]
}
```

What I'm trying to do is filter on the sum of `qtyBid` in a given record. For example, my user could specify that they only want records that have a total qtyBid across all of the `bidCompData` that's greater than 5. My research shows that I can't use `$sum` outside of the `$group` stage in the pipeline but I need to be able to sum just the `qtyBid` values for each individual record. Presently my pipeline looks like this.

```
array(
    array('$project' => $basicProjection), //fields to project calculated earlier using the input parameters.
    array('$match' => $query),
    array('$group' => array(
        '_id' => 
            array('clientID' => '$clientID'),
        'count' => array('$sum' => 1)
    )
)
```

I tried having another group and an unwind before the group I presently have in my pipeline so that I could get the sum there but it doesn't let me keep my fields besides the id and the sum field. Is there a way to do this without using `$where`? My database is large and I can't afford the speed hit from the JS execution.

Comment: Have you tried including the document _id in the $unwind (to know which qtyBid's go together) and $group from there?

Comment: Could you elaborate? Do you mean adding the document _id into the subdocument or some kind of additional information added to the unwind itself.

Comment: Each step of the pipeline produces result documents and you can verify each of your steps, also I believe that the document id (_id) defaults to include. So, your project would include all needed info from the general doc and the $unwind so you would have 1 document for each bidCompData and then could sum the qtyBid by _id in the next step. This might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16448175/whats-the-unwind-operator-in-mongodb

Comment: The problem is that in the $group where I get the $sum of the qtyBid field I lose the other fields in the projection. I still need those for the main group where I group the records by clientID.

Comment: Wouldn't the other fields to be part of the $groups user defined ID?

Comment: Adding the other fields to the $group's _id allows me to keep them through the $group stage but puts them all in the _id value instead of all being side by side on the top level. While it's definitely workable is there any way to get them all on the same level?