# MongoDB C# List the latest of all entries on a sub document

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Is it possible to list all the restaurants and their latest grade, if grades is a an array within a restaurant?

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56bf7957b5e096fd06b755b2"),
    "grades" : [ 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2014-11-15T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "grade" : "Z",
            "score" : 38
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2014-05-02T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "grade" : "A",
            "score" : 10
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2013-03-02T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "grade" : "A",
            "score" : 7
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2012-02-10T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "grade" : "A",
            "score" : 13
        }
    ],
    "name" : "Brunos On The Boulevard",
}
```

I would want to get:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56bf7957b5e096fd06b755b2"),
    "grades" : [ 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2014-11-15T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "grade" : "Z",
            "score" : 38
        }
    ],
    "name" : "Brunos On The Boulevard",
}
```

**Explanation**

The [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35386993/442351) uses the [unwind operator](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/).  There's a really simple explanation of it on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16448763/442351), should anyone be confused by it as I was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option could be doing an aggregate with two operations, an `Unwind` which deconstructs your array field from the input documents to output a document for each element, and later a sort operation by `date` in descending order. This way you can get the result you are expected selecting the first element from the aggregate result:

```
 var result = collection.Aggregate()
                        .Unwind(e => e["grades"])
                        .SortByDescending(e=>e["grades.date"])
                        .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: That seems to work.  I say seems because I don't understand why.

Comment: Just found out I needed to add a `Match` element if I wanted to `ToList` it or I run out of memory!  I didn't expect it to be that bigger query.

Comment: Just read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16448763/442351) which explains unwind really well.

Comment: That's right, that operation tends to confuse a little bit, thanks for share the link