# MongoDB month query on array records

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have one json object in mongodb which looks like this.
JSON Object :

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("58736cfc7d43c305461cdba7"), 

  "pb_event" : [
     {
        "event_type" : "Birthday", 
        "event_date" : ISODate("2016-05-09T13:01:11.967+0000")    
     }, 
     {
        "event_type" : "Aniversary", 
        "event_date" : ISODate("2016-06-09T13:01:11.967+0000")          
     }
  ]
}
```

When i try below query :

`db.temp.aggregate({$project : {month : {$month : "$pb_event.event_date"}}} )`

It gives me error like this :

"Can't Convert from BSON type array To date"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the $unwind operator in MongoDB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16448175/whats-the-unwind-operator-in-mongodb)

Comment: Currently you are dealing with array and mongo tries to convert it to date, you should use $unwind before $project operation